# Filter view based on the users Group

Tags: python, django, permissions, filtering, usergroups

I am trying to filter the query further to only show records where the Groups matches the logged in users group. I am new to Python and not sure how to add an additional filter into the below view.

View

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
   q= request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else '' 
   infs= Infringement.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) |
                                     Q(infringer__name__icontains=q)
                                                                                
                                    )
```

Model

```
class Infringement (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    infringer = models.ForeignKey(Infringer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    groups = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']`
```

I tried adding the below but it doesn't work.

```
infs= Infringement.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) |
                                     Q(infringer__name__icontains=q|) 
                                       (groups=request.user.groups)                                         
                                      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q


@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    infs = Infringement.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(infringer__name__icontains=q),
        groups__user=request.user,
    )
    # …
```